# About MATLAB intlinprog

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

I have a problem with MATLAB intlinprog. I have a problem about assigning worker types to jobs. Each job must assigned to one type of worker. The same type of worker can be assigned to different jobs. There are total time, total risk and assignment constraints. I have written this piece of code in Matlab to solve this problem. But the solution is not feasible. It doesn’t assigned to any worker type to some jobs and assigned two workers types to some jobs.

i (jobs) -> i=1,..,10  ;
j (worker types) -> j=1,..,7

Decision variables: x(i,j): if job i is assigned to worker type j 1, otherwise 0.
(There are 10*7=70 decision variables)

[image]

The mathematical model or problem may seem odd but it is just little part of what actually tried to do.

t(i,j):

```
     117       10000       10000       10000          78         117         179
      17       10000       10000          57          11          17          26
      30          45       10000         102          20          30          45
      47          71       10000         160       10000       10000       10000
      65          99       10000       10000          43          65          99
     150         228       10000         508       10000       10000       10000
      56          85       10000         189          37          56          85
      16          25          36          54          11          16          25
      11          17          25       10000       10000       10000       10000
      43          66          96         146          28          43          66
```

r(i,j):

```
      46       10000       10000       10000          17          32          51
       4       10000       10000           0           1           3           7
       8          12       10000           0           3           5           7
      26          32       10000           0       10000       10000       10000
      25          32       10000       10000           8          15          27
      46          60       10000           0       10000       10000       10000
      18          23       10000           0           9          13          18
       8          10          15           0           3           6           9
       8          12          17       10000       10000       10000       10000
      17          22          31           0           7          13          22
```

MaxTime: 999
MaxRisk: 17

ObjCoef = t(i,j)

My MATLAB code:

```
RHS1 = MaxTime*(ones(10,1));
RHS2 = MaxRisk*(ones(10,1));
RHS3 = ones(10,1);
 
A = [maxrix1; maxrix2];
b = [RHS1;RHS2];
 
C = reshape(ObjCoef',10*7,1);
 
Aeq = matrix3;
beq = RHS3;
 
lb = zeros(10*7,1);
intcon=1:70;
 
[x,z] = intlinprog(C,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb);
x=reshape(x,10,7);
```

The size of matrix1, 2 and 3 are 10x70. I dont't know if their sizes are wrong.

Here is matrix1:

```
117 10000   10000   10000   78  117 179 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17  10000   10000   57  11  17  26  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   30  45  10000   102 20  30  45  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   47  71  10000   160 10000   10000   10000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   65  99  10000   10000   43  65  99  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   150 228 10000   508 10000   10000   10000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   56  85  10000   189 37  56  85  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  25  36  54  11  16  25  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11  17  25  10000   10000   10000   10000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   43  66  96  146 28  43  66
```

Here is matrix2:

```
46  10000   10000   10000   17  32  51  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   10000   10000   0   1   3   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   12  10000   0   3   5   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   26  32  10000   0   10000   10000   10000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   25  32  10000   10000   8   15  27  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   46  60  10000   0   10000   10000   10000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   18  23  10000   0   9   13  18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   10  15  0   3   6   9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   12  17  10000   10000   10000   10000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17  22  31  0   7   13  22
```

Here is matrix3:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

The result:

```
>> reshape(x,10,7)

ans =

         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0    1.0000         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000         0
    1.0000         0    1.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0    1.0000    1.0000         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
         0    1.0000         0    1.0000         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Each row should have been exactly one "1". I cannot find what I did wrong. If you help me, I would be gratefull.

Comment: My GUESS is that you are swapping rows and columns incorrectly here.  ObjCoef is (10,7), 10 rows of 7 columns.  When you transpose it, now it's 7 rows of 10 columns.  The `reshape` is going to give you all of the first column (7 elements) followed by all of the second column (7 elements).  Are you sure that produces the result you want?  Are you sure you're final `reshape(x,10,7)` is in the right order?

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you, I realized that the last step should be x=reshape(x,7,10);. So, if I want to write a constraint over the sum of i and j, how should I do it? That is, if cj is the cost of each worker type, how can I write the constraint c1*x1,1+c2*x1,2+....+c7*x1,7+....+c7*x10,7<=budget?

Comment: Use Problem Based optimization in Matlab. See e.g. https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/sudoku-puzzles-problem-based.html